# How do I run QUnit tests with Grunt through a local server instead of the file system?

Tags: javascript, cookies, gruntjs, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I'm building a small JS object that manages cookies, basic set, get, and remove functions. I've written tests with [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com) that pass in a browser if I'm running against a local server. I'm booting up a server like so:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080`

If I run the tests against the local file system (e.g. file:///) they fail because cookies are host dependent. `document.cookie` is always `""` against the file system. I'd like to continue using my grunt tasks to run the tests but this is a bit of a road block. It looks like someone anticipated this problem but perhaps never found a failing test case: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8954.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `urls` option of `grunt-contrib-qunit` and insert the URL of the page you visit in the browser (Im guessing `http://localhost:8080/test.html` but the path to your tests might be different):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  qunit: {
    all: { options: {
      urls: ['http://localhost:8000/test.html']
    } }
  }
});
```

Then run `grunt qunit` to run the tests. Here are the docs with more examples: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit#testing-via-http-or-https

Comment: This means that I also need to boot up that server separately, huh? Is there a way that grunt can do that automatically? Or alternatively, is there a good way to mock `document.cookie`?

Comment: Isn't `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` booting up a server? If you want to integrate with Grunt, use `grunt-contrib-connect`. Here is an example using the two together: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit#using-the-grunt-contrib-connect-plugin

Comment: I'm hoping to have one command, `grunt test`, that starts the server runs the tests then kills the server. That's ideal. In the meantime, I'll check out `grunt-contrub-connect`. Thanks!